# JPA timeout donot work wit Sql server

Tags: sql-server, jpa, timeout

all.

I has written a program connectting Azure sql DB using JPA, within the code, I set the query timeout as below:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 0);
return this.getEntityManager().find( cls, id,  LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE,map);
```

I hope it will return null immediately in case the query can not get the lock under the row.
but it didnot work, it always blocked there.

Is it something wrong? or did sqlserver driver not support timeout?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is not supported, but if you include the SQL that was generated, this could be confirmed.

You could also try setting the query timeout,

```
"eclipselink.jdbc.timeout"="100"
```

Or, if you are using EclipseLink, you could use,

```
"eclipselink.pessimistic-lock"="LockNoWait"
```